# Непонятный сдвиг влево bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap

Установил `bootstrap 4`. Заметил что есть сдвиг влево. То бишь я разместил элементы а они смещены влево, ни `padding`, ни `margin`-ов нет. Если я задаю `margin-left: 7px` для `body`, то контура блоков становятся в норму - по границе экрана. почему так не пойму.

Вот скриншот. Чистый html. С подключенным bootstrap 4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обернуто в `container-fluid`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На втором скрине видно, что все по границе экрана стоит и никаких проблем нет. В чем вопрос?

Comment: @AndrewB в том и дело что не по границе. не видно закруглений углов у кнопки.

Comment: выкладывайте код текстом - [mcve], по скринам ваши ошибки искать никто не будет

Answer (score 3):

row должен быть вложен в container

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1PRESS</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2PRESS</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: мне не нужно что бы весь контент был в `container`. У меня контент на всю ширину экрана. Но. Я сделал с `container-fluid`, но все равно сдвиг есть. Скриншот в шапке.

Comment: @Tsyklop, используйте полностью сетку, поместите кнопку в колонку(добавил в пример). Сдвиг есть так как у row есть отрицательный margin

Comment: а я и забыл про отрицательный `margin` вижу в стилях. Спасибо.

Comment: Не работает. Мне не нужны `padding`. Я их убрал, и кнопка опять сместилась. `margin` у `row` я убрал.

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот. Самый последний.

Comment: @Tsyklop, если вам нужна кнопка в притык к краю экрана. Зачем вообще использовать в этом случае сетку bootstrap? Поместите в обычный div.

Comment: Я взял кнопку для примера, ибо на ней наглядней про проблему видно. я бутстрп использую во всю. и даже когда я размещаю `nav` и блоки дальше всегда есть сдвиг.

Comment: Я загрузил скриншот ещё один. Последний самый. Если присмотреться то видно что `padding` разные. И ладно бы это был отрицательный `margin` у `row`,о это не так.

Comment: @Tsyklop, отредактировал пример. Я так полагаю вы искали 2 вариант. row no-gutters
Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67150/discussion-between-e-k-and-tsyklop).